# Check the audio player's current playback time every 0.1 seconds

Tags: iphone

How can i use the `CurrentTime` property in the `AVAudioPlayer`to check the audioplayer's current playback time every 0.1 second. and how i can synchronize it with the views in this fashion that after 11 seconds of audiofile first view loads then second view is loaded after 23 seconds  third view is loaded after 27 sec fourth view is loaded after 24 secs  and fifth view is loaded after 24 secs so that is how for each view timer varies.

So that when i pause the audio views update is also paused and when it is resumed views update begins from that point where it was paused.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

set your timers NOT to repeat and just create a new instance of the timer each time the new view loads.